# difference between: Measurable multifunction integrably bounded and Measurable multifunction integrable

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

I read the article "[**Komlós Theorem for Unbounded Random Sets**](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1008744112313)" by G. KRUPA ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1790483)), but I did not understand the difference between:

- Measurable multifunction *integrably bounded*,
- Measurable multifunction *integrable*

(see p. 239).

Answer (score 1):

Let $F:\Omega\to 2^X$ be a measurable multifunction with closed values in the separable Banach space $X$. It seems to be implicitly assumed that $F$ jas nonempty values.

$F$ is *integrably bounded* if the function $\omega\mapsto \sup_{x\in F(\omega)}\|x\|$ is integrable.

$F$ is *integrable* if the function $\omega\mapsto \inf_{x\in F(\omega)}\|x\|=d(0,F(\omega))$ is integrable.

The point of these definitions might be better understood in terms of measurable selections. By the Kuratowski-Ryll-Nardzewski measurable selection theorem, $F$ admits measurable selections. If $F$ is integrably bounded, all selections will be integrable and dominated by a single integrable function. If $F$ is integrable, at least one selection will be integrable.

Comment: Let $\mathcal{P}_{c}(X)$ be the family of all closed subsets of $X$. We know that the space of all measurable multifunctions $F:\Omega\to \mathcal{P}_{c}(X)$ integrably bounded noted by $\mathcal{L}^1_{\mathcal{P}_{c}(X)}$. But what is the notation of  the space of all the measurable multifunctions integrable?

Comment: I don't think the author introduces special notation for integrable multifunctions.

Comment: What are the advantages of the integrable multifunction? And why did the authors present this notion?

Comment: can you give me an example of multifunctions integrable but not integrably bounded ?

Comment: The multifunction with constant value $X$.

Comment: can you give me a book about multivalued integration

Comment: I think "Infinite Dimensional Analysis" by Aliprantis and Border is a great source for material on multifunctions (correspondences in the book).

Comment: Thank you very much, I still have a question that I did not understand : when we talk about the measurable function $f:\Omega\to X $, we assume that the $X$ is equipped with the  Borelian $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(X)$. but, to say that a multifunction $ F:\Omega\to 2^X $ is measurable. Which $\sigma$-algebra  $\mathcal{A}$ should be equipped in $2^X$?

Comment: Measurability of a multifunction is generally not defined in terms of a $\sigma$-algebra on $2^X$. In special cases, something like that is possible though. If $X$ is a separable metrizable space and $\mathcal{K}$ the family of nonempty compact subsets of $X$ and if $f:\Omega\to 2^X$ has values in $\mathcal{K}$, then measurbility of $f$ corresponds to measurability with respect to the Hausdorff metric topology on $\mathcal{K}$. This is Theorem 18.10 in the mentioned book.